# SAS import messy data

Tags: sas

I have this SAS code and I want to output it as Fruit data with Date Description and Supplier as the columns

```
data want;
infile datalines firstobs=2 dsd; 
input Date Description Supplier ;  
format Date ddmmyys8.; 
datalines;
Date, Description, Supplier 
14/2/21, "Jumbo size, sweet, organic", Fresh Ltd
13/3/21, "Fresh, juicy, sweet", Polan Ltd
12/1/21, Fresh and sweet, "30.kg", Japanko Ltd
13/4/21, "Sour and tasty", from Japan, "Juicy", Pan International
14/5/21, "Organic, honey sweet, fresh", Koreania Ltd
17/6/21, "Juicy, pulp", Grocer Fresh 
18/4/21, "Honey sweet", Korea, "fresh", Hanko Ltd
;
run;
```

I tried the code above but still was not able to import the dataset successfully. May i know how can i ensure that the data imported has only Date Description and Supplier columns?

Comment: What output do you want for the lines that more than 3 values on them?  Do you want multiple observations? Do you want some of the extra values combined into one of the two character variables? Which one?

Comment: Can you just have whoever created the file re-create it with proper formatting so that it can be parsed unambiguously?

Comment: The three values should be under description

Answer (score 0):

The main thing wrong with your data step is you did not tell SAS how to define the variables, so by default the INPUT statement will try to create them as numeric.  You also did not use any informat to read the date strings as actual date values.

It is hard to tell what you want to do with the extra values on some of the lines. What do they mean?  Do you just want to ignore them?  If you include them where should they go?

Here is code that assumes each line has one date and multiple pairs of description/supplier values.

```
data want;
  infile datalines firstobs=2 dsd truncover;
  length Date 8 Description $30 Supplier $30 ; 
  informat date ddmmyy.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  input Date Description Supplier @;
  do until(description=' ');
    output;
    input description supplier @;
  end; 
datalines;
Date, Description, Supplier 
14/2/21, "Jumbo size, sweet, organic", Fresh Ltd
13/3/21, "Fresh, juicy, sweet", Polan Ltd
12/1/21, Fresh and sweet, "30.kg", Japanko Ltd
13/4/21, "Sour and tasty", from Japan, "Juicy", Pan International
14/5/21, "Organic, honey sweet, fresh", Koreania Ltd
17/6/21, "Juicy, pulp", Grocer Fresh 
18/4/21, "Honey sweet", Korea, "fresh", Hanko Ltd
;
```

Results:

```
Obs          Date    Description                    Supplier

  1    2021-02-14    Jumbo size, sweet, organic     Fresh Ltd
  2    2021-03-13    Fresh, juicy, sweet            Polan Ltd
  3    2021-01-12    Fresh and sweet                30.kg
  4    2021-01-12    Japanko Ltd
  5    2021-04-13    Sour and tasty                 from Japan
  6    2021-04-13    Juicy                          Pan International
  7    2021-05-14    Organic, honey sweet, fresh    Koreania Ltd
  8    2021-06-17    Juicy, pulp                    Grocer Fresh
  9    2021-04-18    Honey sweet                    Korea
 10    2021-04-18    fresh                          Hanko Ltd
```

Here is a version that assumes the extra words all belong to the Description field.

```
data want;
  infile datalines firstobs=2 dsd truncover;
  length Date 8 Description $50 Supplier $30 ; 
  informat date ddmmyy.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  input Date Description @ ;
  do _n_=1 to countw(_infile_,',','mq')-3;
     input Supplier @;
     description=catx(', ',description,supplier);
  end;
  input supplier;
datalines;
Date, Description, Supplier 
14/2/21, "Jumbo size, sweet, organic", Fresh Ltd
13/3/21, "Fresh, juicy, sweet", Polan Ltd
12/1/21, Fresh and sweet, "30.kg", Japanko Ltd
13/4/21, "Sour and tasty", from Japan, "Juicy", Pan International
14/5/21, "Organic, honey sweet, fresh", Koreania Ltd
17/6/21, "Juicy, pulp", Grocer Fresh 
18/4/21, "Honey sweet", Korea, "fresh", Hanko Ltd
;
```

Results

```
Obs          Date    Description                          Supplier

 1     2021-02-14    Jumbo size, sweet, organic           Fresh Ltd
 2     2021-03-13    Fresh, juicy, sweet                  Polan Ltd
 3     2021-01-12    Fresh and sweet, 30.kg               Japanko Ltd
 4     2021-04-13    Sour and tasty, from Japan, Juicy    Pan International
 5     2021-05-14    Organic, honey sweet, fresh          Koreania Ltd
 6     2021-06-17    Juicy, pulp                          Grocer Fresh
 7     2021-04-18    Honey sweet, Korea, fresh            Hanko Ltd
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw, what does this line do "countw(_infile_,',','mq')-3;"?

Comment: It sets the upperbound for the DO loop.  The COUNTW() function counts words.  So when there are more than 3 words on the line the DO loop will read the extra words one by one and appends them to DESCRIPTION.